# Finding duplicates in a multi-dimensional table

Tags: lua, duplicates, key-value, lua-table

A slightly altered version of the below permitted me to filter unique field values out of a multi-dimensional table (dictionary style).

[ url ] http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Remove_duplicate_elements#Lua

```
items = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,"bird","cat","dog","dog","bird"}`
flags = {}
io.write('Unique items are:')
for i=1,#items do
if not flags[items[i]] then
  io.write(' ' .. items[i])
  flags[items[i]] = true
end
end
io.write('\n')`
```

What I'm lost at is what 'if not ... then ... end' part actually does. To me this is sillyspeak but hey, it works ;-) Now i want to know what happens under the hood.

I hope multi-dimensional does not offend anyone, I'm referring to a table consisting of multiple row containing multiple key-value pairs on each row.

Here's the code i'm using, no brilliant adaptation but good enough to filter unique values on a fieldname

```
 for i=1,#table,1 do 

 if not table2[table[i].fieldname] then
    table2[table[i].fieldname] = true 
 end 
 end

 for k,v in pairs(table2) do
     print(k)
 end
```

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question with an edit. Please make it an answer and accept it.

Comment: Don't use `table` as a variable name.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i use table to illustrate the code, as i do with fieldname

Comment: it's perfectly fine to use `table` as a variable name. Just keep in mind that you can't access the global `table.*` functions if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this is the code which worked for me. I've been asked to post it as a separate answer so here goes.

```
for i=1,#table1,1 do 

 if not table2[table1[i].fieldname] then
    table2[table1[i].fieldname] = true 
 end 
 end

 for k,v in pairs(table2) do
     print(k)
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function findDuplicates(t)
    seen = {} --keep record of elements we've seen
    duplicated = {} --keep a record of duplicated elements
    for i = 1, #t do
        element = t[i]  
        if seen[element] then  --check if we've seen the element before
            duplicated[element] = true --if we have then it must be a duplicate! add to a table to keep track of this
        else
            seen[element] = true -- set the element to seen
        end
    end 
    return duplicated
end
```

The logic behind the `if seen[element] then`, is that we check if we've already *seen* the element before in the table. As if they key doesn't exist `nill` will be returned which is evaluated which is false (this is *not* the same as boolean `false`, there are two types of false in lua!).

You can use this function like so:

```
t = {'a','b','a','c','c','c','d'}
for key,_ in pairs(findDuplicates(t)) do
    print(key)
end
```

However that function won't work with multidimensional tables, this one will however:

```
function findDuplicates(t)
    seen = {} --keep record of elements we've seen
    duplicated = {} --keep a record of duplicated elements
    local function traverse(subt)
        for i=1, #subt do
            element = subt[i]
            if type(element) == 'table' then
                traverse(element)
            else
                if seen[element] then 
                    duplicated[element] = true
                else
                    seen[element] = true
                end 
            end 
        end 
    end
    traverse(t)
    return duplicated
end
```

Example useage:

```
t = {'a',{'b','a'},'c',{'c',{'c'}},'d'}
for k,_ in pairs(findDuplicates(t)) do
    print(k)
end
```

Outputs

```
a
c
```

---

```
t = {a='a',b='b',c='c',d='c',e='a',f='d'}

function findDuplicates(t)
    seen = {}
    duplicated = {}
    for key,val in pairs(t) do
        if seen[val] then
            duplicated[val] = true
        else
            seen[val] = true
        end 
    end 
    return duplicated
end
```

This works the same way as before but checks if the same *value* is associated with a different *key* and if so, makes note of that value as being duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm a novice programmer so i over-used the multi-dimensional wording here. I'm still getting used to the raw power lua offers ;-) At times it seems hard to control ;-)

My table looks like

    { { field1 = "value1", field2 = "value2",....,field9 = "value9"   },</br> { field1 = "value1", field2 = "value2",....,field9 = "value9" } .... }

Comment: @SaintCrusty no worries. Lua was my first language :) It was really frustrating at times. Understanding tables is actually quite hard, it seems easy once you do though but I know I struggled quite a bit. That and metatables! Stick with it though :) If this answered your Q you should consider accepting it. Oh I'll update my answer accordingly!

Comment: @SaintCrusty is that better now?

Comment: I'm new here so bear with me to address the requirements ;-) Tables are indeed quite a challenge, i've not dared look at metatables. Still, these concepts do seem ingenious and practical.